# Stream<int[]> displaing the result

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

How can I display result `Stream<int[]> allResults = list.stream();`

I try:

```
allResluts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Arrays.toString` for printing array:

```
stream.forEach(ints -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line:

```
Stream<int[]> allResults = list.stream();
```

It means, that every element of stream is an array, you might do this:

```
allResults.flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or, as @YCF_L suggests, even simplier:

```
allResults.flatMap(Stream::of).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: not down-voter but `int` not `Integer` you need boxed

Comment: just replace `.flatMap(Arrays::stream)` with `.flatMap(Stream::of)`

Comment: or `flatMapToInt`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks guys for suggestions:)

Comment: I don't think he talks about arrays of arrays at all. I mean from his initialization it could be said so, but his implementation speaks otherwise and assuming his level of Java, I would think he meant just printing an array of numbers using streams.

Comment: @MS90 you might be right, but I'll try to use given code, not the assumptions;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like following:

```
int[] numbers = {2,4,7,4,3,6};
IntStream.of(numbers).forEach(System.out::print);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have int[][] like some suggests, use following code:

```
int[][] numbersOfNumbers = {{1, 25, 63}, {4}, {42, 53},{3,6,4,7,3}};
//same as above with int[][]
Stream.of(numbersOfNumbers).flatMap(Stream::of).forEach(i->IntStream.of(i).forEach(System.out::print));
Stream.of(numbersOfNumbers).flatMap(Stream::of).forEach(numbs->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbs)));
```